# Перевести вычисления на видеокарту

Tags: python, tensorflow

Не направите в нужную сторону? Установил Python3.6. Выполнил [рекомендации](https://www.pytorials.com/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows/) Python по установке TensorFlow для вычислений на GPU.
Установил Cuda9.0. Установил Visual Studio Community с пакетом обновлений Pack3.
Установил `virtualenv`, Создал переменную с помощью `virtualenv`. Установил TensorFlow-gpu 1.5. Вывел на экран `Hello TensorFlow` с помощью [этой статьи](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585095/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-constant)
. Проверил пути - переменные среды от Cuda и Python прописаны. Нашел в интернете тестовый код, в нем вычисления переводятся на видеокарту, запустил не работает. Приложение успешно закрывается, но никаких вычислений не происходит.

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
 y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
 W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
 b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

 def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

 def bias_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

 def max_pool_2x2(x):
 return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
  b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
  h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
  b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

  h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
  h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
  b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

  h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
  h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

  W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
  b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

  y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

  cross_entropy = 
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, 
logits=y_conv))
  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

 with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, 
log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(10000):
     batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
      if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
       train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Какого компонента недостает чтобы GPU успешно включилось? Спасибо!

Comment: Извините, набросал свой код и gpu включилось, но только на 10%  как можно увеличить загрузку gpu ближе к 100%